# Flutter `6 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found.` Try adding the missing arguments

Tags: flutter

Please help ::

Here in main.dart file access to rest api when in setState()
with 6 positional argument(s) expected, but 1 found.

Please see in screenshot.

user_data.dart
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUeC8.png
main.dart
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy3WR.png

Help in thanks.

Comment: can you please add the code where is error show?

Answer (score 0):

well as the error say, you are passing 1 argument where the constructor is expecting 6. so just remove the five parameters starting from the id and only keep userData. Like this:

```
UserData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic userData){
  // same code here
}
```

Comment: hi bro.... user_data.dart  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUeC8.png  main.dart https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy3WR.png

Comment: yea bro... i passed the 6 arguments on user_data class 
UserData({required this.id,required this.email,
  required this.firstName,required this.lastName,required this.avatar});

Comment: you should only add userData and remove the rest if you will not pass them

Comment: any way thanks :) Bro

Answer (score 0):

You should not expect anything but the data in your .fromJson method. So keep the userData, but get rid of this.id, this.email, etc.
Also you can get rid of the late keyword, as the constructor method will initialize the values.